# Material index animation

Tags: animation, mesh, materials

Is it possible to create an animation to switch between materials (material slots) in a mesh with multiple materials ?
Thanks

Comment: Use Mix node & animate the factor from 0 to 1.

Comment: I look for an option without blending, e.g. animating active material index.